# How do I cast Class FooObject to class BarObject which both implement interface IObject?

Tags: c#, interface, casting, implementation

I have 2 classes which implement the same interface. But somehow I cannot cast them from one to another.

Here's an example:

```
public interface IObject {
    // ...
}

public class FooObject : IObject {
    // ...
}

public class BarObject : IObject {
    // ...
}
```

-

If I do it like this, VS will mark it as `Cannot convert type 'FooObject' to 'BarObject'`

```
var foo = new FooObject();
var bar = (BarObject)foo; // Build error
```

-

If I do it like this, there is no build error, but when called, it throw `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'FooObject' to 'BarObject'.`

```
var foo = new FooObject();
var bar = (BarObject)(IObject)foo; // No build error, but InvalidCastException gets thrown
```

-

So, how do I cast/parse/convert an implementation (`FooObject`) of an interface (`IObject`) to another implementation (`BarObject`) of that same interface?

## Solution:

I fixed this by creating an explicit conversion operator:

```
public class FooObject {
    // ...
    public static explicit operator BarObject(FooObject fooObject)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Thanks to [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster).

Comment: You can't. Both `Cat` and `Dog` can implement `IAnimal`, but you can't cast one to the other - at least not without writing implicit or explicit conversion operators. What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I created a ```public static explicit operator BarObject(FooObject fooObject)``` and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I just made a similar suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55047697/880990.

Comment: If you use this extension method, you probably will be right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672742/cast-class-into-another-class-or-convert-class-to-another

Comment: @Olivier nice, that's what that duplicate was missing.